# Unable to read textarea value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am using textarea in foreach loop. These textarea controls are shown in the modal popup to take the input from the user. However textarea value always returning undefined. If I set the default value of textarea in html, then it is returning only the default value and not user's entered value.

I am able to read the value of textarea which is not in modal popup.Please let me know how can I achieve this.

I am using jQuery to get the values.

```
@foreach (var service in ServiceTypes)
  {
   <div class="cell large-3 small-6 noc-check-box pop-up" data-target="#minermod_@serviceID"><img src="@Html.Glass().Editable(service,x=>x.Icon.Src)">
<span>@Html.Glass().Editable(service, x => x.ServiceType)</span>
       <div id="minermod_@serviceID" class="hide">
                                        <div class="modification-popup dp-section-rte">
                                            @Html.Raw(service.ServiceInfo)
                                            <input class="button small primary expanded " data-target="minermod_@serviceID" type="button" value="@(selectButtonText.TryGetValue("Select", out defaultLabelValue) ? defaultLabelValue : string.Empty)">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pop-up" data-target="#desc_@serviceID">

                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-selected-text="@(Selected.TryGetValue("Selected", out defaultLabelValue) ? defaultLabelValue : string.Empty)"
                                       data-select-text="@(selectButtonText.TryGetValue("Select", out defaultLabelValue) ? defaultLabelValue : string.Empty)"
                                       class="cell button secondary">
                                        @(selectButtonText.TryGetValue("Select", out defaultLabelValue) ? defaultLabelValue : string.Empty)
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="desc_@serviceID" class="hide">
                                    <div class="modification-popup dp-section-rte">
                                        <textarea cols="25" rows="7" id="textarea_@serviceID"></textarea>
                                        <input class="button small primary expanded " id="btn_@serviceID" data-target="btn_@serviceID" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript: SetServiceDescription(this);">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                serviceID++;
                            }

function SetServiceDescription(val) {
    debugger;
    var parent = $(val).parent();
    var button_id = val.id;
    var row_id = button_id.replace('btn_', '');
    var textarea_id = '#textarea_' + row_id;    
    var comment = $(textarea_id).val();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you use some kind of templating solution (`@foreach (var service in ServiceTypes)`).

From the symptoms you describe, the `id="textarea_@serviceID"` is probably not getting replaced with an unique ID. (Perhaps because you wrote `serviceID++;` in HTML?)

Check the [browser inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#The_Inspector_DOM_explorer_and_CSS_editor) to see what the actual element on the page looks like and add logging to see the value of `textarea_id`.

Comment: Ids are generating properly like textarea_0 , textarea_1 and so on.

Comment: Now _"add logging to see the value of `textarea_id`"_ just before you try to access it: `$(textarea_id).val();`.